# Passing typesafe config conf files to DataProcSparkOperator

Tags: apache-spark, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, typesafe-config, google-cloud-composer

I am using Google dataproc to submit spark jobs and google cloud composer to schedule them. Unfortunately, I am facing difficulties.

I am relying on `.conf` files (typesafe config files) to pass arguments to my spark jobs.

I am using the following python code for the airflow dataproc:

```
t3 = dataproc_operator.DataProcSparkOperator(
   task_id ='execute_spark_job_cluster_test',
   dataproc_spark_jars='gs://snapshots/jars/pubsub-assembly-0.1.14-SNAPSHOT.jar',
   cluster_name='cluster',
   main_class = 'com.organ.ingestion.Main',
   project_id='project',
   dataproc_spark_properties={'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions':'gs://file-dev/fileConf/development.conf'},
   scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform', dag=dag)
```

But this is not working and I am getting some errors.

Could anyone help me with this?
Basically I want to be able to override the `.conf` files and pass them as arguments to my `DataProcSparkOperator`.
I also tried to do

```
arguments=`'gs://file-dev/fileConf/development.conf'`:
```

but this didn't take into account the `.conf` file mentioned in the arguments .

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr You need to turn your `development.conf` file into a dictionary to pass to `dataproc_spark_properties`.

Full explanation:

There are two main ways to set properties -- on the cluster level and on the job level.

1) Job level

Looks like you are trying to set them on the job level: `DataProcSparkOperator(dataproc_spark_properties={'foo': 'bar', 'foo2': 'bar2'})`. That's the same as `gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --properties foo=bar,foo2=bar2` or `spark-submit --conf foo=bar --conf foo2=bar2`. Here is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/spark) for per-job properties.

The argument to `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` should be command line arguments you would pass to java. For example, `-verbose:gc`.

2) Cluster level

You can also set properties on a cluster level using `DataprocClusterCreateOperator(properties={'spark:foo': 'bar', 'spark:foo2': 'bar2'})`, which is the same as `gcloud dataproc clusters create --properties spark:foo=bar,spark:foo2=bar2` ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties)). Again, you need to use a dictionary.

Importantly, if you specify properties at the cluster level, you need to prefix them with which config file you want to add the property to. If you use `spark:foo=bar`, that means add `foo=bar` to `/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf`. There are similar prefixes for `yarn-site.xml`, etc.

3) Using your `.conf` file at the cluster level

If you don't want to turn your  `.conf` file into a dictionary, you can also just append it to `/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` using an [initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/) when you create the cluster.

E.g. (this is untested):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euxo pipefail

gsutil cp gs://path/to/my.conf .
cat my.conf >> /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

Note that you want to append to rather than replace the existing config file, just so that you only override the configs you need to.