# How to pass Spark job properties to DataProcSparkOperator in Airflow?

Tags: apache-spark, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to execute Spark jar on Dataproc using Airflow's [DataProcSparkOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#dataprocsparkoperator). The jar is located on GCS, and I am creating Dataproc cluster on the fly and then executing this jar on the newly created Dataproc cluster.

I am able to execute this with DataProcSparkOperator of Airflow with default settings, but I am not able to configure Spark job properties (e.g. `--master`, `--deploy-mode`, `--driver-memory` etc.).
From documentation of airflow didn't got any help. Also tried many things but didn't worked out.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To configure Spark job through DataProcSparkOperator you need to use [`dataproc_spark_properties`](https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataProcSparkOperator) parameter.

For example, you can set `deployMode` like this:

```py
DataProcSparkOperator(
    dataproc_spark_properties={ 'spark.submit.deployMode': 'cluster' })
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52358439/3227693) you can find more details.